# How can I print the entire webpage of this url into a pdf file?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I try to print https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/ into a pdf file using two ways:

- used chrome browser by hitting ctrl-p,
- used wkhtmltopdf with various options about javascript.

But I can only print the beginning part of the webpage (imagine the webpage is paginated, only the first page content is printed into the first page of pdf file, and the following pages are blank).

I wonder what is the reason that I can only print part of the webpage?

How can I print the entire webpage into a pdf file?

Thanks.

ps: I also would like to print the code snippets in the webpage with horizontal or vertical scroll bars in their entirety. But that is not the first priority at this moment. If necessary, I will ask in a future post.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean. I tried printing it with bullzip pdf printer (Community Edition) and get the same result. But... if you first save it as web page (single page, HTML only) and then print as pdf it prints everything just fine - but you lose some minor markup.

Comment: PS: and when you mark/highlight the text you want to keep in the HTML - before printing - it also ignores the header & footer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try the extension [GoFullPage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en)

Now here i have to write more stuff otherwise comment could not be saved . maybe the Editors will change this and i don"t need to write nothing usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Open this webpage: printfriendly.com

Paste your URL there, then click on PDF and you can save the webpage as PDF on your Computer, if you want you can also print directly from there.

You can also remove parts you don't want by clicking them...